# how to send additional data to a function

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I'm tying to send a token to an address using ethers.js and here is my code:

```
contract.transfer(address , amount)
```

I want to send additional data like "helloworld" to this function to use it later. I tried this:

```
contract.transfer(address , amount , {
data: "helloworld"
})
```

but it gives me error:

```
cannot override "data"
```

is it possible to do this?
how can I send the data?
or is there a way to save additional data to blockchain using one transaction?
note: the transfer function is from BUSD token

Answer (score 1):

The transfer function you're using likely doesn't have a data field.  You need to assign a data input or use a function that either stores the data or emits it an event to store in order to "keep" the data on the blockchain.

[Assign metadata to a transaction](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48095/assign-metadata-to-a-transaction)

Comment: but i'm using a deployed contract. i'm working with BUSD token contract and i cant change it. is there any way to send data to it? i want to use it off-chain?

Comment: not really a way to do this in the EVM unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You can either use

- [ERC-777 token standard that has receiving callable and data fields](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-777)
- Use ERC-20 `approve()` and `transferFrom()` pattern where you pass the extra data to the function that calls `transferFrom()`

Comment: because i'm using a deployed contract i cant use erc777. i'm using BUSD token contract and it's erc20. for second one i'm not using that because it's not safe it's possible that when user approves my contract after that the user empty his account and i won't have a chance to use transferfrom function.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding how approve() and transferFrom() works. Please read https://xyproblem.info/, edit your questions and add more background and context what you are doing and why and then we can give you a better answer.